# WPF application fall to "the application isn't responding" on virtual machines and Citrix

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

There is some desktop application that based on WPF. The application has one method that takes 2 and more minutes to process.

To don't freeze the GUI, I perform the operation in background and show some progress window. Briefly, the code is:

```
ProgressViewModel model = new ProgressViewModel();
model.Worker = new Task(() => LongTimeMethod());
ProgressWindow window = new ProgressWindow(model);
window.Owner = mainWindow;
window.ShowDialog();
```

The ProgressWindow runs the task after it has been loaded.

The application can show "the application isn't responding" during running as the MainWindow don't process events.

Notes:
1) There isn't problem on usual PC (only VMs and Citrix)
2) The LongTimeMethod performs hard local computing, but it takes only one thread.

I understand that it is almost impossible just give me an answer for this strange case. But I would like to get a piece of advice at least. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the .NET version. The problem has been solved after update .NET from 4.6.0 to 4.6.2.